# Angular 1.5 ng-repeat in nested keys instead of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Hi I am new to Angular and I need some feedback from someone that has more knowledge than me. I will explain in detail my issue. I have to create a table, in the majority of cases I would loop through an array of data using ng-repeat. However this time my data structure is different, the API is returning keys instead of strings and nested keys instead of arrays, the last level does contain an array.

**The Data**

```
{ATLA:
  {NECBTEST2012:
     {FRMFM-HD:
        [{date:"2017-09-27", run_rate:23},
        {date:"2017-09-28", run_rate:23}]
         }
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table >
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th> Market</th>
              <th> </th>
              <th>Average</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th ><form >
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Filter market">
              </form></th>
              <th> </th>
              <th></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in rc.runRate">
              <td>{{key}}</td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat-end class="slide-toggle-js">
              <td colspan="3" >
                  <div  class="toggle-me" >

                  <table>
                      <thead>
                      <tr >
                          <th>Syscode</th>
                          <th>Network</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Average</th>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>
                              <form>
                                  <input class="form-control"  placeholder="Filter Syscode">
                              </form>
                          </th>
                          <th>
                              <form>
                                  <input class="form-control"  placeholder="Filter Network">
                              </form>
                          </th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>


                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody ng-cloak>
                      <tr  ng-class-odd="'stripe-row-odd'" ng-class-even="'stripe-row-even'" ng-repeat="(key, value) in key">
                          <td>{{key}}</td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td> </td>

                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </div>
```

**Desired Result**

In the first ng-repeat I am able to display the first key which is ATLA in the table row, however, when I try to iterate through the next key which is FRMFM-HD I am not able to. I want to learn and be a better programmer, anyone with more knowledge and any feeback will be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

second ng-repeat should not be on key,actually is should be on value of key inside your data holder object like.

Replace key with rc.runRate[key].

key ==>             string

rc.runRate[key] ==> Object

```
<tr  ng-class-odd="'stripe-row-odd'" ng-class-even="'stripe-row-even'" ng-repeat="(subkey, value) in rc.runRate[key]">
     <td>{{subkey}}</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td> </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, now I can display the second key which is NECBTEST2012, how I could I access the third key? I used the value argument but it displays all of the objects instead. Thank you for taking your time and answering my question

Comment: You can go with rc.runRate[key][subkey]